# Nhibernate mapping value object with references as properties

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have following entities
`Country`, `State`, `City`

I have also `User` entity.

`Country`, `State` and the `City` does not have relationship with user entity. 
`User` does not have direct relationship with `Country`, `State` or `City`.

I want to be able to update user address details in a way that
user will select country, state and city and save this values. 
I'm thinking to introduce `Address` value object which will store this user address information.

Is this good idea? How would you handle this scenario?

I'm using nhibernate orm and mapping using Conformist (mapping by code approach)
So I was thinking to map Address as value object

```
Component(c => c.Address, AddressMap.Mapping());

public class AddressMap
    {
        public static Action<IComponentMapper<Address>> Mapping()
        {
            return c =>
            {
                c.Property(p => p.Country);
                c.Property(p => p.State);                    
                c.Property(p => p.City);
            };
        }
    }
```

having this in `UserMap`

```
Component(c => c.Address, AddressMap.Mapping());
```

I'm getting following error

> The type initializer for 'NHibernate.SessionProvider' threw an
>   exception. {"Could not determine type for: Model.Country, ..., for
>   columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Country)"}

Without this line `Component(c => c.Address, AddressMap.Mapping());` in `UserMap` I do not have any error (also I do not have Address value object mapped :).

Answer (score 2):

I would say, that issue here comes from the fact, that `Country` won't be value type *(string including)*, but a reference. If that is the case, we cannot mapp it as `c.Property()` but as a reference:

```
c.ManyToOne(p => p.Country, "CountryId"); // reference

c.Property(p => p.State);                 // value types represented 
c.Property(p => p.City);                  // by values in columns
```

See this: [Mapping-by-Code - ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html) for more details

```
ManyToOne(x => x.PropertyName, m =>
{
    m.Column("column_name");
    // or...
    m.Column(c =>
    {
        c.Name("column_name");
        // other standard column options
    });
    ...
    // many more
```